# Linux - Shared Home Directories

Tags: linux

I have a small lab with Linux machines and two servers. As the administrator I want to permit user settings and project files to be available when users log in on any machine. What server processses do I need on the servers?

Answer (score 1):

You need shared home directories. Typically this is accomplished by using NFS exports on your server. This will take data on the server and make it available to other systems via NFS. Then, on each workstation, `autofs` is employed to automatically mount the user's home directory when they connect, and automatically un-mount when the user disconnects. This allows them to have access to their data regardless of which machine they sign into.

Getting this set up is a fairly trivial task for someone well-versed in unix administration, but it sounds like you're fairly new to this. There are umpteen guides online on how to set up shared home directories using NFS. I'd recommend that you choose and try to implement the steps in one of those guides. If you run into problems, come back to Serverfault and ask away - we'll do our best to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NFS
Longer answer: This is a pretty broad and encompassing topic, and there are many plusses and minusses to different techniques.  I suggest you read up on NFS and then if you have specific questions about specific tasks, those would be better suited as questions, otherwise start with any of the HOWTOs about NFS and go from there.